# Show Tag information on mouse hover while in edit mode

Tags: feature-request, edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

When looking at questions and you put your mouse over a tag, you get the following result:

[image: tag example image]

But when I am editing a question, sometimes I suspect there is an unnecessary tag (such as the one in the image), but in edit mode, the tag profile doesn't pop up.

It would be helpful if that tag information pops up on the mouse hover.

If I get a popup that shows 1,000 followers, then I know I can probably leave the tag as is.  Right now, I had to open the question again in a second tab (using Chrome) just to double-check the tag information.

Comment: @WouterJ How can this be a duplicate when this post is much older than the others?

Comment: @WouterJ It might be a duplicate and the answer there provides a workaround.  However, it would be nice to have an official response on this.  I see no reason why there is no hover information on the tags when editing and clearly it causes some people issues.  Why is there no response?